# Oracle NO_COPY instruction in java API

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle11g

Oracle provides a statement compiler hint, [NO_COPY](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/nocopy-hint-to-improve-performance-of-parameters-in-plsql.php), that can be used to improve performance of SQL statements, particularly those that involve large data structures.

My problem is that, try as I might, I can't find any reference on how to use this feature through the Java API. All I can find is this [javadoc for Oracle Fusion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/apirefs.111240/e17493/oracle/javatools/db/plsql/PlSqlParameter.html) which, as I understand, is a separate middleware package that can be applied over the database layer (presumably at great expense), which is not what I need.

**EDIT**

I am fairly new to database programming and it is quite possible that I have missed something important here!

I am using CallableStatements to call a prepared statement already written in the database. Since I have to tell the Java API the type of each returned parameter with registerOutParameter(), I had assumed that I would also need to tell the Java API to use NO-COPY (ie if the JDBC driver can't work out the types from the procedure definition in the database, I figured I would need to tell it to use NO_COPY as well).

Have I got this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOCOPY` is used when you declare and define a PL/SQL subprogram.  You don't need to specify it when you call the procedure or function -- much like you don't specify the type or mode (IN/OUT) in a call.